# using object in PHP without instantiating first

Tags: php, mysql, oop, object

I'm new to PHP and have been trying to get some experience with it. I have experience with C++  but it has been a while so this is a refresher.

So, I stumbled upon JPMaster's PHP login script and I'm confused by one aspect on the registration form. If you look in the HTML table, the object $form is used however it's not instantiated anywhere on this page, yet from what I can tell the object would start here too because it's new information being added and not just passed through. When viewing 'session.php' (another file in the login system) the objects $form and $error are created in the functions that they're used, such as login, register, edit account, and so on.

Here's a link to download the full login script. The download is at the bottom of the wall of code. http://www.evolt.org/node/60384

I thought I had a solid understanding of OOP, or maybe it's something unique to PHP, but can anyone give a simple explanation as to where/when you can create a new object? I figured since the object is first used on this form it must be created here too. Can anyone point me in the direction of an article or something that may clear up my confusion?

```
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user" maxlength="30" value="<? echo       $form->value("user"); ?>"></td><td><? echo $form->error("user"); ?></td></tr>
```

The specific part I'm referencing is in the table such as in this row. I understand that it's written like this so the correct type of error message will appear beside the row, I'm just confused why the object isn't created on this form even though the information first starts on this page once the form is submitted.

```
<?

include("include/session.php");
?>

<html>
<title>Registration Page</title>
<body>

<?

if($session->logged_in){
echo "<h1>Registered</h1>";
echo "<p>We're sorry <b>$session->username</b>, but you've already registered. "
     ."<a href=\"main.php\">Main</a>.</p>";
}

else if(isset($_SESSION['regsuccess'])){
/* Registration was successful */
if($_SESSION['regsuccess']){
  echo "<h1>Registered!</h1>";
  echo "<p>Thank you <b>".$_SESSION['reguname']."</b>, your information has been added to   the database, "
      ."you may now <a href=\"main.php\">log in</a>.</p>";
 }
 /* Registration failed */
 else{
 echo "<h1>Registration Failed</h1>";
 echo "<p>We're sorry, but an error has occurred and your registration for the username  <b>".$_SESSION['reguname']."</b>, "
      ."could not be completed.<br>Please try again at a later time.</p>";
 }
unset($_SESSION['regsuccess']);
unset($_SESSION['reguname']);
}

else{
?>

<h1>Register</h1>
<?
if($form->num_errors > 0){
echo "<td><font size=\"2\" color=\"#ff0000\">".$form->num_errors." error(s) found</font>    </td>";
}
?>
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user" maxlength="30" value="<? echo    $form->value("user"); ?>"></td><td><? echo $form->error("user"); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30" value="<? echo  $form->value("pass"); ?>"></td><td><? echo $form->error("pass"); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" value="<? echo   $form->value("email"); ?>"></td><td><? echo $form->error("email"); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="right">
<input type="hidden" name="subjoin" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Join!"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="left"><a href="main.php">Back to Main</a></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the bottom of the session.php page, you'll see this:

```
$session = new Session;

/* Initialize form object */
$form = new Form;
```

Remember that when files are `include()`'d in PHP, any variables/objects defined/instantiated in that file are done so in the scope of where the `include()` directive was. In effect, even though these two objects are in another file, they're treated as if they were literally part of your own script and are at the same scope level.

Comment: Exactly. When you use `include()`, it's as if all of the code in the included file is copy and pasted into the including file.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I missed the $form=new Form; on the session.php page. Like I said, it's been a while since I've done any programming so that completely slipped my mind.

Comment: Just updated a form I was working on by initializing the object on a different form and it worked perfectly. Thanks again!